# Good way to handle Q Promises in Waterline with Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, q, waterline

I have a problem that I'm importing some data and each new row depends on previous row being added (since each row has its `order` attribute set based on current maximum `order` from other objects). The flow is that I first try to find object with the same name, if not found I first check maximum `order` and create new object with order + 1 from that query.
I tried doing this with Q promises which are available under Waterline. I tried using `all` method as well as combining queries with `then` from Q docs:

```
var result = Q(initialVal);
funcs.forEach(function (f) {
    result = result.then(f);
});
return result;
```

But all objects had the same `order`, just like they would be executed in parallel, instead of waiting for the first chain to finish.

I finally found a solution with recurrency, but I doubt it's the best way of working with promises. Here's the code that works (+ needs some refactor and cleaning etc.), to show the rough idea:

```
function findOrCreateGroup(groupsQuery, index, callback) {
      var groupName = groupsQuery[index];

      Group.findOne({ 'name' : groupName }).then(function(group) {
        if (!group) {
           return Group.find().limit(1).sort('order DESC').then(function(foundGroups) {
               var maxOrder = 0;
               if (foundGroups.length > 0) {
                   maxOrder = foundGroups[0].order;
               }

               return Group.create({
                   'name' : groupName,
                   'order' : (maxOrder + 1)
               }).then(function(g) {
                 dbGroups[g.name] = g;

                 if (index + 1 < groupsQuery.length) {
                   findOrCreateGroup(groupsQuery, index + 1, callback);
                 } else {
                   callback();
                 }

                 return g;
               });
            });
        } else {

          dbGroups[group.name] = group;

          if (index + 1 < groupsQuery.length) {
            findOrCreateGroup(groupsQuery, index + 1, callback);
          } else {
            callback();
          }

          return group;
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: In short, I think that recursion is the right approach for this problem. Note that with promises, recursion will not bottom out the stack. Each handler gets a fresh stack. The only thing I would improve is the redundancy of the terminal case. There should be a way to frame this so that case only needs to be expressed once.

Comment: Yeah - as I wrote it's just a proof of concept for myself that I can make that work. It has to be refactored and cleaned. Thanks @KrisKowal